# Find the area between $y = -x^2+4x$ and $y = -x +4$.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I'm a high schooler. I'm studying for an exam and got stuck with calculating the area between two functions.

Picture of the question :

> (1) $y = -x^2+4x$
>   (2) $y = -x +4$
>   $A(1,5), B(4,0)$
>   [image]

I should calculate the area from A to B it's highlighted

I have tried calculating it more than once, but the answer that I get is wrong. Here is one of my attempts:

[image: image 2]

I's not clean or tidy, but anyway can you guys please tell me what is wrong? The answer should be 27.

---

Here is the full question (it's in Hebrew):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6_IPgklxcLM0FxVE13c0tNSHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For tidiness, please format your work in future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Mm... i'' not sure what do you mean with format ? , but i'm sorry for the no tidiness part

Comment: Click the link. Learn to use MathJax. Type up your posts. Handwriting is often sloppy and hard to read. You can find the tutorial [HERE.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you :) , well actually I posted this from my phone ...

Comment: $A$ does not lie on the curves. Sure, the picture is correct ? Or do we have $A(1/3)$ ?

Comment: I think A should be $(1,3)$, and the area should be $\frac{9}{2}$.

Comment: I will post another 2 pictures and explain as hard as i can (I got the computer ... )

Answer (score 2):

I think you're doing the wrong subtraction. It should be the integral of the parabola minus the integral of the line.

By the way, the intersection points are $A(1,3)$ and $B(4,0)$.

There is a very simple strategy for computing these areas. Find the intersection points:
$$
\begin{cases}
y=-x^2+4x \\[4px]
y=-x+4
\end{cases}
$$
that gives $-x^2+4x=-x+4$, that is, $x^2-5x+4=0$. The roots are $1$ and $4$. Then the area is
$$
\int_1^4 (-x^2+4x)\,dx+\int_4^1(-x+4)\,dx
$$
In other words, you start from one intersection point and follow the perimeter in clockwise order. This also works for more than two curves; if one part of the path is a vertical segment, it contributes $0$.

This amounts to doing
$$
\int_1^4\bigl((-x^2+4x)-(-x+4)\bigr)\,dx=\int_1^4(-x^2+5x-4)\,dx=
\Bigl[-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{5x^2}{2}-4x\Bigr]_1^4
$$
Now it's just a tedious computation.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for $ x\in [a,b]$ area between f(x) and g(x) on segment [a,b] can be calculated using formula
$$
P=\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-g(x))dx
$$
In your example $f(x)=-x^2+4x$ and $g(x)=-x+4$

$
P=\int_{1}^{4}((-x^2+4x)-(-x+4))dx=\\
\int_{1}^{4}(-x^2+4x+x-4)dx=\\
\int_{1}^{4}(-x^2+5x-4)dx=\\
\int_{1}^{4}-x^2dx+5\int_{1}^{4}xdx-4\int_{1}^{4}dx=\\
\frac{-x^3}{3}|_{1}^{4}+5\frac{x^2}{2}|_{1}^{4}-4x|_{1}^{4}=\\
-\frac{64}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+40-\frac{5}{2}-16+4=\\
-21+44-\frac{37}{2}=\\
23-\frac{37}{2}=\\
\frac{9}{2}
$

Answer (score 0):

The area is `19/3`

```
f1[x_] = 4 x - x^2;
f2[x_] = 4 - x;
```

The two functions intersect for

```
soln = Solve[f1[x] == f2[x], x]
```

> {{x -> 1}, {x -> 4}}

The intersection points are

```
pts = {x, f1[x]} /. soln
```

> {{1, 3}, {4, 0}}

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 4},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 PlotLegends -> {f1[x], f2[x]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

The shaded area between the curves is

```
Integrate[Abs[f1[x] - f2[x]], {x, 0, 4}]
```

> 19/3

Alternatively,

```
Integrate[f2[x] - f1[x], {x, 0, 1}] +
 Integrate[f1[x] - f2[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

> 19/3

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 4 &&
     Min[f1[x], f2[x]] <= y <= Max[f1[x], f2[x]]},
   {x, y}];

RegionPlot[rgn, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

```
Area[rgn]
```

> 19/3

```
RegionMeasure[rgn]
```

> 19/3